# WebAPI is sending me a whole HTML page on login timeout. How to use this response in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code to call a service in the client side of a business application I'm developing (with .NET WebAPI in the backend):

```
resource = $resource(apiEndPointManager.endpoints.masterValues, {}, {  
    GetByCode: {
                url: '{0}/:code'.format(apiEndPointManager.endpoints.masterValues),
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function(data) {
                    var response = angular.fromJson(data);

                    if (response.length) {
                        // the response is an array, so convert it into an object
                        var object = {};
                        for( var i = 0; i < response.length; i ++) {
                            object[i] = response[i];
                        }
                        return object;
                    } else {
                        return response;
                    }
                }
            },
```

When I'm logged in, this service works well and the *data* variable is filled with the json data I need. However, if I've timeout, the *data* variable is filled with a whole HTML page (the login dispatch page more specifically).

I have no idea about how should I handle this situation and properly redirect to that page in AngularJS. What is the best practice to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Is your web api hosted in IIS? If so, I suppose that the reason for that behavior is because when you are not authorized, the web api returns status Not Authorized, and IIS redirects to the login page which becomes the response your request. To avoid that try to host your web api using OWIN and Windows Service for instance.

Comment: @xxxmatko yes it is hosted in IIS. However I work in a big company environment and that is kind of a policy I can't avoid (therefore I have to stick with IIS unfortunately...). Is there any other workaround?

Comment: You can turn of authentication for the WebAPI url location, in the web.config, on using Authorize attribute annotation on the WebAPI controller or actions. I do not know how is your application configured. Or you can deploy the WebAPI to a separate application with anonymous access. Do you need to have authorization turned on for the WebAPI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved my problem by creating a special interceptor that catches the response, and if the response is an HTML page, performs a redirection to the login page.

```
resource = $resource(apiEndPointManager.endpoints.masterValues, {}, {  
    GetByCode: {
            url: '{0}/:code'.format(apiEndPointManager.endpoints.masterValues),
            method: 'GET',
            interceptor: resourceResponseInterceptor
    }
```

Interceptor:

```
angular.module('app.services')
.factory('resourceResponseInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$injector', function ($rootScope, $q, $injector) {

    var userContext = $injector.get('$userContext');

    return {

        response: function (response) {
            // when session is already timed out, Siteminder will return the login page with an OK code
            // so check that response is HTML and if it is redirect user to the Dispatch page
            if ($.isHtmlResponseContent(response)) {
                window.location.href = userContext.data.LogoutUrl;
                return $q.reject(response);
            }

            return response.resource;
        }
    };
}]);

$.isHtmlResponseContent = function(response) {
    var isHtmlContent = false;
    var contentType = response.headers('Content-Type');
    if (contentType) {
        isHtmlContent = contentType.indexOf('text/html') >= 0;
    }
    return isHtmlContent;
};
```

Hope it helps someone with the same problem!